# How to access Active Directory data from an ASP.Net Core Program (Dependency Injection)

Tags: c#, .net-core, active-directory

I am working on a Restful API Project with .NET 7, I need to be aple to connect to an active directory records using dependency injection, update some attribute or create new records.

I am new to Core and MVC.
whit SQL Server I download the required Nuget packages
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools,
add the connection string to the appsetting.json, create the Model Context inject the service in the program.cs file.
but I am not familiar with how that could work or what packages to use for the Active Directory?

I tried to search for how to connect to the Active Directory, but most of the answers I found are about the users authentication, which is not what I need. and it didn't have a specific packages or method to work with update/insert process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AD, and not Azure AD I think that you need :

`System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.

Something like this:

```
try
        {
            string ldapPath = "LDAP://CN=Users,DC=YourDomain,DC=com"; 
            string username = "yourUsername"; 

            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath);
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry)
            {
                Filter = $"(SAMAccountName={username})"
            };

            SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

            if (result != null)
            {
                DirectoryEntry userEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

                // Update properties
                userEntry.Properties["propertyToChange"].Value = "newValue";

                // Commit changes
                userEntry.CommitChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("Update successful");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User not found");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
```

EDIT:

As a service it could be something like this :

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;

public interface IActiveDirectoryService
 {
   bool UpdateUserProperty(string username, string propertyName, 
   string newValue);
 }

public class ActiveDirectoryService : IActiveDirectoryService
{
       private readonly string _ldapPath;

   public ActiveDirectoryService(string ldapPath)
   {
    _ldapPath = ldapPath;
   }

public bool UpdateUserProperty(string username, string 
propertyName, string newValue)
{
    try
    {
        using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry(_ldapPath))
        {
            using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
            {
                searcher.Filter = $"(SAMAccountName={username})";
                SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    using (var userEntry = 
             result.GetDirectoryEntry())
                    {
                        userEntry.Properties[propertyName].Value 
                        = newValue;
                        userEntry.CommitChanges();
                        Console.WriteLine("Update successful");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("User not found");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception occurred: {ex.Message}");
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

And register as service :

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Other service registrations

        // Register ActiveDirectoryService
        services.AddScoped<IActiveDirectoryService>(provider =>
            new ActiveDirectoryService("LDAP://CN=Users,DC=YourDomain,DC=com"));
    }

    // Other methods...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I may use this solution in the end, but what I wanted was to set the connection using dependency injection in the programe.cs file like how I did it with the sql server.

Comment: I edited my answer as example of the service.

Comment: The edited solution you provided is what I was looking for. I tried it and it worked successfully. Thank you.